Whenever I add, modify, or remove a menu, my WordPress website does not update unless I perform a CSS regeneration. How can I address that problem?
My question is:
Whenever I add, modify, or remove a menu, my WordPress website does not update unless I perform a CSS regeneration. How can I address that problem?

What are you using?  How are you "regenerating" your CSS?  Sorry, but you haven't provided any usable information here.  A theme's stylesheet(s) should not have any impact on whether a wp_nav_menu() call is processed or not.  I suspect you're using a Settings panel included with some theme and your CSS actions are flushing the cache.  Where/how are you creating your menu?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
